# Composer Script echo

Tags: php, composer-php

What is the best way to echo to the console in a `composer.json` script? For example, I have used the scripts section to create a custom installer and at the end I want to display a message in the console.

At the moment i'm simply doing an echo like this

```
"scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "clear",
        "echo \"\n\nInstallation Complete\""
    ]
}
```

This works, but it prints out the command and the echo in the console, so it ends up looking like this.

[image]

As composer outputs all of the custom commands that are in the scripts anyway, it doubles up and looks ugly!

Whats the best and cleanest way to use the [composer scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) to echo a message to the console?

Comment: Have you tried to add a `script-description` for your custom script. https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#custom-descriptions-

Comment: Personally i output message to the console inside my script, using symfony/console for exemple. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/formatterhelper.html

Answer (score 6):

I just had to do something similar today and didn't feel like writing a whole script/class for this.

I got it working better than I expected by abusing two things:

1. text preceded by hash marks is not executed in most consoles
2. turns out that the script command is passed through [symfony console output](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/coloring.html)

#### So for example:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "# <info>For your info</info>",
      "# <comment>A comment</comment>",
      "# <error>Error!!!!</error>",
      "# <href=https://symfony.com>Symfony Homepage</>"
    ]
  }
```

#### Produces:

[image]
Tada!

#### Caveats:

1. the hash mark and angle bracket will be shown anyway
2. the command is executed anyway - terminals that do not understand the hash mark will produce weird / potentially damaging results

Answer (score 4):

If you use a PHP class instead of using shell directly for your scripts, you can use Composers' IO system to write to the console.

For example, create a class similar to this:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyApp\Composer;

use Composer\Script\Event;

class ScriptHandler
{
    public static function myScript(Event $event): void
    {
        // Your script here
    }
}
```

`Composer\Script\Event` class has a method called `getIO()` which you can use to get the instance of `Composer\IO\IOInterface`, which then has a method `write`, making your `myScript` method looking something like this:

```
public static function myScript(Event $event): void
{
    $event->getIO()->write('foo'):
}
```

Finally, to use this class, just reference it in your `post-update-cmd`:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "MyApp\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::myScript"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I Need it to be something I can run inside the `scripts` section of the `composer.json` file, thank you anyway though

Comment: You can reference the class inside the `scripts` section with the FQCN and method name and it should be pretty much similar to running the script directly.

Comment: I'm not quite 100% sure what you mean, please can you elaborate?

Comment: I've updated my answer to elaborate. I hope it makes it more clearer.

Comment: That works nicer, but it still echo's the name of the function called (in this example, `MyApp\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::myScript`) on the output

Comment: Do you know how to return exit codes? I need 0, 1, 2, etc... I do return the number, but seems not using it as exit code for the script

Comment: @nelson6e65 I don't think you can. The command methods use a `void` return type in their signature, signaling that they should return nothing. Meaning, Composer will not use the return value of the script.

Comment: @EdiModrić Hi. I discovered that using `exit($code)` will return the code as error. So, you can catch an error if it occurs, write an error message and then exit that code to prevent other scripts to run or whatever (Note: Even using `exit(0)` will be taken as an error exit).

Comment: @commonpike You can use a semantic class and method names, so the print is not that ugly. Like `Install::completed`. Just make sure you autoload the class in your `autoload-dev` section.

And, by the way, you can run commands inside PHP with `exec()` and `shell_exec()`, so there is no need to run "clear" as an additional script (https://www.php.net/manual/function.shell-exec.php).